# stock.picking extension onchange for state not working

Tags: python, onchange, odoo, odoo-8

I have the following extension:

```py
from openerp import models, api, fields

class MyExtension(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.picking'

    some_instances = fields.One2many(comodel_name='some.some',
                                     inverse_name='return_picking')

    @api.onchange('state')
    def changed_return_picking_state(self):
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

When I transfer the picking or force it's availability, the onchange is not triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@api.onchange` only works if the value is modified in a view in the web client. For `stock.picking`, the state attribute is generally modified on the server side by a call to write, therefore your decorated method is not called.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `@api.depends` instead, onchange operates as gurney alex mentioned